# PHP/HTML: If url is domain.co.uk/?debug then

Tags: php, javascript, html, debugging, url

I know this must be a nooby question and I apologize but I can't find a straight forward answer anywhere!

Basically what I want to do is, if someone visits http://domain.co.uk/?debug then I want it to display additional information such as the code version or any other information I enter.

Again, I am sorry for the question but I really appreciate your help!

Thank you.

Comment: I would definitely not even do this functionality. Anyone visiting your site can type that and get information about your server that you show... Bad move, don't do it. Set up an admin page instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Hope4You](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1119677/hope4you) pointed out, this is bad practice. But somehow this is very useful when deploying our application. One trick is to set up a "in development" flag.

```
<?php
define('DEVELOPMENT_SERVER', TRUE);

if (DEVELOPMENT_SERVER)
  require 'debug_tools.php';
```

where `debug_tools.php` contains the code from [MarcB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) and other helper functions.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (isset($_GET['debug'])) {
    echo "Get the raid! There's bugs!";
}
```

Comment: Yes? The question is tagged with PHP, so using PHP code to answer a PHP question would seem to be the obvious thing to do?